# PHP Mail to send text message functions differently on two servers

Tags: php, email, sms

I'm using the following PHP mail command to email on two different linux based servers behind firewalls.

1.)  Both work when a regular email address is used (username@domain.com)

2.)  Only one of the servers is able to successfully send a message when the string $to value is a mobile provider's text message email equivalent.

The server that works when sending a text message appears says simple: 220 mail.domain.com ESMTP

The server that does NOT work shows the following:  220 domain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

Works fine on both servers:

```
mail('username@domain.com', '', 'Testing');  

//mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Only successfully sends and is received on one server:

```
mail('5556667777@txt.provider.net', '', 'Testing');  

//mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Comment: php doesn't send mail. `mail()` just uses whatever local MTA is installed (e.g. sendmail, postfix, exim,...). mail() is the equivalent of walking your letter down to the street corner and tossing the envelope into the mailbox.

Comment: @MarcB thanks so much!  okay...so the server that CAN send a txt message is running xinetd and the server that canNOT send a txt message is running postfix.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry...not xinetd...I meant ESMTP

Comment: esmtp is a protocol. check the postfix logs to see what's happening to the email after php hands it over.

Comment: You may want to look at PEAR Mail. Better handling of mail messages. Also, `220 mail.domain.com ESMTP` is a successful response banner. So check the logs on your Relay MTA as @MarcB suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The comments were great, thanks.  It was how Postfix was configured.  The mobile provider was knocking it down as spam.  I made a few changes to authenticate via a valid smtp server and it works fine.  Thanks for the help!